# electron prevent multiple instance with middle click

Tags: node.js, electron

I am tying to make single instance [Electron](https://github.com/electron) application.
I am using [app.makeSingleInstance](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v0.36.10/docs/api/app.md#appmakesingleinstancecallback) , see my sample below.

**SingleInstance issue with middle click :**

1. Single Instance works if I click on app.exe 2nd time
2. It does not work if I middle click on a link inside my app

**What I need:**

1. Make electron app singleInstance and ensure it remaisn single instance even with middle click.
2. I dont want to compeltey disable middle click in my app as at some places, I have a use case for them on non-link items

**How to reproduce:**

1. use repo: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
2. replace existing with my `index.html` and `main.js` , see below
3. `npm install` and then `npm start`

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Hello World!</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>app.makeSingleInstance()</h1>
    <a href="$">Middle Click on it</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')
let mainWindow
const isSecondInstance = app.makeSingleInstance((commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
  if (myWindow) {
    if (myWindow.isMinimized()) myWindow.restore()
    myWindow.focus()
  }
})
if (isSecondInstance) {
  app.quit()
}
function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The middle click does not create a new instance of your application, but rather a new instance of a `BrowserWindow`. You can disable middle-clicks on `a` (actually all) elements using the [`auxclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/auxclick) event.

In your main window's HTML you could put the following JavaScript to disable middle-clicks on link elements if you do not want to redirect these events to your default browser:

```
// The following function will catch all non-left (middle and right) clicks
function handleNonLeftClick (e) {
    // e.button will be 1 for the middle mouse button.
    if (e.button === 1) {
        // Check if it is a link (a) element; if so, prevent the execution.
        if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    // Attach the listener to the whole document.
    document.addEventListener("auxclick", handleNonLeftClick);
}
```

But you can also choose to redirect the middle-click events to your standard browser, namely via Electron's [`shell`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell) module:

```
// Require Electron's "shell" module
const { shell } = require("electron");

function handleNonLeftClick (e) {
    // e.button will be 1 for the middle mouse button.
    if (e.button === 1) {
        // Check if it is a link (a) element; if so, prevent the execution.
        if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a") {
            // Prevent the default action to fire...
            e.preventDefault();

            // ...and let the OS handle the URL.
            shell.openExternal(e.target.href);
        }
    }
}

// Also attach the listener this time:
window.onload = () => { document.addEventListener("auxclick", handleNonLeftClick); }
```

You could remove the `if (e.button === 1)` if you also want to block right-clicks on `a` elements.